# How to resolve Managed Property Type?

Tags: 2013, search

In SharePoint search you can create managed properties with following types:

```
Text
Integer 
Decimal 
DateTime 
YesNo 
Binary
```

In my case I tried to create managed properties in PowerShell for these field types:

```
"SPFieldMultiLineText"
"SPFieldChoice"
"SPFieldMultiChoice"
"SPFieldNumber"
"SPFieldCurrency" 
"SPFieldDateTime" 
"SPFieldBoolean" 
"SPFieldUser" 
"SPFieldUrl" 
"HtmlField" 
"ImageField"
"LinkField" 
"SPFieldLookup"
"SPFieldCalculated"
"OutcomeChoiceField"
"SummaryLinkField" 
"MediaField" 
"TaxonomyField"
"SPFieldGuid"
```

What managed property type matches to each field type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Text**: "SPFieldMultiLineText","SPFieldChoice","SPFieldMultiChoice","SPFieldUser","SPFieldUrl","LinkField","SPFieldLookup","HtmlField","SPFieldCalculated","SummaryLinkField","SPFieldGuid","OutcomeChoiceField"

**Integer**: 
"SPFieldNumber"

**Decimal**: "SPFieldNumber","SPFieldCurrency"

**DateTime**: "SPFieldDateTime"

**YesNo**: "SPFieldBoolean"

**Binary**: "ImageField","MediaField"(I don't really know about this one, but I think it should be like images)